# Cannot define class in Emacs racket-repl-mode

Tags: emacs, racket

I can define a class like so in a racket repl that I start from my shell. I'm using v6.12

```
(define book-class%
  (class object%
    (field (pages 5))
    (define/public (letters)
      (* pages 500))
    (super-new)))
```

Everything works fine. But when I try the same in emacs, executing the expression via `C-x C-e`, the output is

```
; class: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
```

Writing the same definition directly in the emacs racket shell shows the same error.

Why is this happening and how can I change my repl to allow the creation of classes?

Comment: You probably have to import `racket/class` by writing `(require racket/class)`.

Comment: That import does the trick. Any idea why the emacs repl requires it, but the racket repl started from bash might not?

Comment: It is because `racket/class` is part of `racket`, but not `racket/base`. An as far as I know `racket-mode` in Emacs defaults to `racket/base`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ["racket-mode" package](https://melpa.org/#/racket-mode) is really multiple modes. The main two are:

- `racket-mode` for editing Racket source files.
- `racket-repl-mode` a REPL.

If you're doing <kbd>M-x racket-repl</kbd>, then `racket-repl-mode` opens directly. It is associated with no `racket-mode` buffer or `.rkt` file. It is "empty".

As soegaard said, it has only bindings from `racket/base`.

As Alexis said, you could then enter `(require racket/class)` -- or `(require racket)` -- if you want to use things from `racket/class`.

---

Although you could use `racket-repl-mode` "stand-alone" the way you described, the intended use is a work flow like:

1. Visit a `.rkt` file (which will automatically be a `racket-mode` buffer).
2. <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> a.k.a. <kbd>M-x racket-run</kbd>.
3. Now you have a `racket-repl-mode` buffer with a prompt inside the namespace of the `.rkt` file.

---

Even if you care only about using the REPL stand-alone, you could make a little `.rkt` file to use to open the REPL. You could call it (say) `config.rkt`. Maybe it is simply:

```
#lang racket
```

Plus any `require`s you typically use.

Now you can start the REPL by opening `config.rkt` (or whatever you called it) and doing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>.